# Best Local Storage Techniques for a Meteor/Cordova App

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am building a Meteor/Cordova application that I need to store data even between application restarts and be able to start-up the app offline with collected data from previous uses, i.e I need more than the minimongo that runs during the application's single session(s). I have looked into HTML5 storage but that maxes out at 5MB. What other techniques can I use to store data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the [ground:db](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db) package it works perfectly offline.

Concept (from docs.)

> Localstorage is simple and widely supported - but slow - Thats why we
>   only use it for caching databases and methods + trying to limit the
>   read and writes from it.
>
> GroundDB saves outstanding methods and minimongo db into localstorage
>   - The number of saves to localstorage is minimized. Use Ground.resumeMethods
>
> When the app loads GroundDB resumes methods and database changes -
>   made when offline and browser closed.