# Whats the best way to store local data in meteor mobile app?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am developing android app in meteor. Now I want to store logged in users data. Whats the best way to store logged in users data. I checked `session` and `local storage` values are changed once the app is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bug somewhere, local storage is supposed to be persistent. Check this stack [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881059/localstorage-cleared-on-app-restart-with-cordova-1-7-and-ios-5-1-1).

Session is not supposed to be persistent, it's just a terrible and confusing name. There's a [package](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session/) to make it persistent.

You can use Web [Storage](http://caniuse.com/#search=storage), it's well supported on decent browsers. Chrome has a decent [article](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage) on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Not much offline storage options in Meteor as of now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576205/best-local-storage-techniques-for-a-meteor-cordova-app). Best tool so far is probably [GroundDB](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a Collection to store that infos and use that collection throught GroundDb meteor package ? it will store everything into localStorage and will use it when the app is offLine. It can also re-sync data from the collection when connection is back.

Here is the link : [GroundDb on atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/ground/db)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working example repo](https://github.com/rafaelquintanilha/offlinecontacts) and [blog write up](http://rafaelquintanilha.com/offline-app-with-meteor-and-cordova/) by Rafael Quintanilha